# Do Windows updates make the version/build number higher?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have an old Windows 10 install DVD from 2015. I always install the latest updates. Does that mean that I have the newest Windows version/build?
Or do I have an old Windows version with some updates and I should buy a new DVD release to have the latest version/build?
Do Windows updates make the version/build number higher?
Sorry for my English, I hope you understand:
Is using an old Windows 10 DVD and updating it with the newest updates the same as buying the latest Windows 10 DVD and install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to buy another DVD release to have the latest version. Automatic updates keep your OS up-to-date no matter the date you've bought it. Still, if you aren't sure which version/build you have, you can check it from `Settings > System > About` and trigger a manual update from `Settings > Update & security > Windows Update > Check for updates`.

Comment: The current Windows 10 .ISO is given freely to all users.  The only reason to purchase Windows 10 would be for the license itself.